# What does the word "verifactive" mean?

Tags: meaning, latin, neologisms

In Introduction to Functional Grammar, in the section on conjunction, Halliday labels the conjuncts "actually", "in fact" and "as a matter of fact" as "verifactive".  He does not expound, except for an example, which I quote:

> *Interviewer: You ... went to Vassar as an undergraduate, and then came back to Iowa ... Smiley: **Actually**, there was a year in there
> where after I finished Vassar I went to Europe ... [verifactive]*

I can't find "verifactive" in a dictionary, and Google brings up references to Halliday.  I presume it's a neologism.  What is it supposed to mean ("verifactive" not "actually")?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it shows a lack of research. The example comes from the same blog that explains "verifactive": http://systemictheory.blogspot.com/2020/04/the-conjunctions-that-mark-cohesive.html

Comment: @Greybeard The link in your comment is to a scanned table from the book, which labels the conjuncts "actually", "in fact" and "as a matter of fact" as "verifactive", as I said in my OP.  I don't know how you jumpted from that to an "explanation"; furthermore, I don't know how you jumpted from that to voting to close the question because of "lack of research".  This is at best misleading and at worst a non sequitur.

Comment: In [Language Log](https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=1086#:~:text=The%20common%20core%20function%20of,real'%20(SOED%2023).), Liberman shows Lenk's analysis, which posits **three different** pragmatic-marker usages of _actually_, in addition to two 'propositional usages': << In Lenk's analysis [1998], 'actually' has a number of different propositional senses: "to indicate that a situation exists or happened, or to emphasize that it is true or correct"; as a way to indicate surprise; and simply as an intensifier.... She identifies ...

Comment: three different "discourse marker" uses: with objections; as an opinion marker; and to introduce a topic shift. ... >>  [slightly adapted]. But this shows that attempting to deduce how Halliday uses 'verifactive' from an example using 'actually' where the author's classification of the usage isn't otherwise explained must involve guesswork. I'd consider OP's usage to be of the "positively corrective" class of pragmatic markers (thanks to  
@Seymour Azzes).

Answer (score 2):

OED3 does not contain *verifactive* **at all:**

[image: Screenshot of OED search results]

So one can only guess...

- *veri-* combining prefix indicating ***truth***.
- *-factive* = factitive. OED has a citation including the word: "Factive Verbs are such as may be said to make..a thing to be of a certain character, by deed, word or thought."

Factitive verbs **do** something to their object, expressed by a complement: "English examples of factitive verbs are ‘to *make* a man king’, ‘to *call* a person a fool’, ‘to *paint* the door green’, ‘to *let* a bird go’, ‘to *condemn* a prisoner to death’." (OED)

Thus a word which is *verifactive* at least indicates, if it does not actually create, truth.

Comment: The OED is sadly irrelevant in this case, which is too bad since the man who used the term was a Brit: the linguistic Michael Halliday.

Comment: ... The fact that a 'word' **_isn't_** listed in OED can be very important.

Answer (score 1):

The Ngram indicates that the usage of the word 'verifactive' began in 1985 and the comment below by @Seymour Azzes indicates that there is evidence of its usage only from the publication of Halliday's Functional Grammar from that date.

[Ngram - verifactive](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=verifactive&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

Online Etymology Dictionary comes back with a non-result as does OED.

The word is in technical usage by linguists - see ['Corpus Analysis in Corpus Linguistics'](https://www.cram.com/essay/Corpus-Analysis-In-Corpus-Linguistics/F35QQHLJ55Q)

The concomitant word 'petrifactive' is present in OED and its meaning is simply 'causing petrifaction'.

Therefore 'verifactive' is applied to that which causes 'verifaction' or rather 'verification'.

See [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/141893?redirectedFrom=petrifactive#eid).

Comment: OP's example is of an (at least partial) corrective (taking Grice's maxim of quantity as an ideal). 'Actually' is a pragmatic/discourse marker used to introduce a corrective (even if this is, as here, giving a fuller account rather than a stark contradiction). // I'd not consider 'indeed' to have this function.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I think of it as "positively corrective".  Halliday uses the label "corrective" for "or rather, at least, to be (more) precise", which I think of as "negatively corrective".

Comment: @Seymour Yes ... it's obviously stipulatively defined in-house jargon. Fraser [[Journal of Pragmatics, 1999](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0378216698001015)] gives other terminology. I like 'positively corrective' = adding necessary info, vs 'negatively corrective' = correcting incorrect info.

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating Conjunction: Clarification

> Halliday & Matthiessen (2014: 616): Here the elaborated element is not
> simply restated but reinstated, summarised, made more precise or in
> some other way clarified for purposes of the discourse. **There are
> seven subtypes (corrective, distractive, dismissive, particularising,
> resumptive, summative, verifactive)**, realised by different sets of
> conjunctions; they are set out in Table 9-6, and illustrated below:

> Calculations by Anderson show that ozone depletion at the 410- and
> 420-K isentropic surfaces between August 23 and September 22 can be
> almost entirely explained by the amount of ClO present if one assumes
> that the ClO-ClO mechanism is effective. At the 360-K surface, the
> calculated ozone loss is somewhat less than the observed loss. At
> least we can say that above about the 400-K level, there does seem to
> be enough ClO to explain the observed ozone loss. [corrective]

> Customer: What’s pepperoni? – Operator: Pepperoni? It’s a round, it’s
> a pork product. – Customer: Is it? Oh okay. No I don’t want that.
> Anyway, um – can I have one of them? I’ll pay the two dollar extra:
> the – what do you call it? the seafood.[dismissive]

> Interviewer: You grew up in St. Louis, Missouri, went to Vassar as an undergraduate,
> and then came back to Iowa for your graduate work. – Smiley: Actually,
> there was a year in there where after I finished Vassar I went to
> Europe with my then husband and we hitchhiked around, wondering what
> to do. [verifactive]

[Elaborating Conjunction: Clarification](http://systemictheory.blogspot.com/2020/05/elaborating-conjunction-clarification.html)

The foregoing is a post (which I cannot see the entirety of) on a website called:
**Systemic Functional Linguistics
A Guide For The Theoretically Ready Willing & Able**

And here is another guide to these Halliday terms regarding conjunctive cohesion or clarifying discourse markers (as I like to call them):

> We thus come to the third way, according to Halliday, through which
> cohesive linkages can be established between clauses: through the use
> of conjunctive adjuncts, which consist of certain adverbial groups or
> prepositional phrases. **The use of conjunctions to link clauses**, or
> its lack, has a parallel in classical rhetoric with the concepts of
> polysyndeton and asyndeton. In polysyndeton, relatively many
> conjunctions are used to link clauses, but in asyndeton, conjunctions
> are avoided. [...]
>
> Like the tactic linkages between clauses within the sentence in our
> study of clause complexing, the cohesive conjunctive linkages between
> clauses (which may extend beyond the sentence) can also be seen in
> terms of elaboration, extension, and enhancement. The conjunctive
> adjuncts which give rise to elaboration and extension are given in the
> first table below, whilst those which give rise to enhancement are
> given in the next table (**adapted from section 9.4 of the earlier
> editions of Halliday's Introduction**; see also the slightly different
> tabulation in the third edition [...]

Thus, there are different types of clarifying adjuncts:
[There is a chart, part of which I have given below].
Clarification

**corrective**, “rather” Examples: or rather, at least, to be (more) precise

**distractive,** “by the way” Example: by the way, incidentally

**dismissive,** “in any case” Example: in any case, anyway, leaving that aside

**particularizing**, “in particular” Example: in particular, more especially

**resumptive**, “to resume” Example: as I was saying, to resume, to get back to the point

**summative,** “in short” Examples: briefly, to sum up, in conclusion

**verifactive**, “actually” Examples: actually, in fact, as a matter of fact

Taken from: Literary Stylistics:
Workshop Notes no. 18(c)
[Course](https://courses.nus.edu.sg/course/ellibst/lsl18c.html)
University of Singapore